# Parsing URL paths

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse out the paths in a URL such as:

```
http://www.website.com/first-path/second-path/third-path
```

I have the following regex: `[^/\s][^/]*[^/\s]*`

I need to extract `first-path`, `second-path`, and `third-path` individually, just need to ignore the `http://www.website.com/`

Edit: There can be zero or `n` number of paths. I can use capture groups as well.

Edit 2: Using `http://(.*?)/(?!.*\/$)(.*)`, I can isolate the 2nd group but need to isolate each path

Edit 3: Using `http://(.*?)/(.*?)(?:/(.*?)/(.*?))?$` fails when there are only two paths:

```
http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path/third-path
http://www.example.com/first-path
http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path
```

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: @Matt.G not using a specific language

Comment: will there be always 3 path segments?

Comment: @Matt.G There can be zero or `n` number of segments

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?<=\G\/|\.com\/)([\w-]+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpObXJ/1)